# How expensive is it to dynamically insert DIVs using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

After much debate with myself, I decided that I would like to dynamically create divs that will overlay a canvas.  But I have a question.  How expensive is it to dynamically create divs?  Would it be utter chaos if I were to have a full canvas--1000x1000--filled with 16x16 divs?  And would it be even worse if there were 1000 hidden divs? (or displayed:none)?

Or should I just compare mouse coords with a container that will hold x,y positions, and having to render images to the canvas.

Im leaning towards the first being more efficient but I am unsure.  Maybe there is a middle ground to this.

Very interested in the replies!  Thanks for your time.

(if this is a repost, I am sorry, I tried to google)

Comment: IMO it's about a wage between easily read ,changeable code and speed, as long as the speed isn't significant different you should go for accessibility before speed, which I believe JavaScript would give you

Comment: It sounds like your project might be a good candidate for [`<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on how the DIVs are inserted into the DOM. Ideally, you should build out the DIVs in memory and inject them into the DOM in a single action. There are a variety of ways to do this (see the [benchmark test cases](http://jsperf.com/render-in-memory-vs-direct-dom-insertion/7) for a variety of full examples).

If you use jQuery, you can build elements in memory like this:

```
var i = 1000;
var aHTML = [];
while (i--) {
  aHTML.push("<div>a new div</div>");
}
var sHTML = aHTML.join("");
var domElmt = $(sHTML);
```

and then to insert that DIV into the DOM:

```
$('body').append(domElmt);
```

If you don't use jQuery, you'll need to use `createDocumentFragment`, `cloneNode`, `appendChild`, etc. These are native browser methods and will be the fastest (I can achieve about double speeed with Chrome 21 on an Intel Q8200) but using these native methods will trickier to use if you need to build out a complicated DOM structure. The native methods may also have [cross-browser support issues](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/cloneNode#compatibilitysection).

If you're interested in how this works, check out this old post by John Resig: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Now contrast that with a method where you access the DOM with each DIV:

```
var i = 1000;
while (i--) {
    $('body').append("<div>a new div</div>");
}
```

Fewer lines of code, but very inefficient.

**[Run the jsPerf DOM Insertion Benchmark](http://jsperf.com/render-in-memory-vs-direct-dom-insertion/7)**

For that benchmark on my computer with Chrome, it's 38x faster to render the DIVs in memory and inject all at once than to separately inject each individual DIV into the DOM.

Ultimately, DOM traversal/manipulation is what you want to avoid. Repetitive DOM traversal/manipulation are expensive operations and will definitely bog down on a 1000x1000 canvas of DIVs--especially on older browsers.

**EDIT:** Since I posted this question, @RobG, @Devu and I put together a bunch of different benchmark tests for various DOM insertion methods. The fastest method on some browsers (Chrome, Safari) is to use `createDocumentFragment`, `cloneNode`, etc. but surprisingly on other browsers (FireFox 15, Internet Explorer, etc) creating a long string of HTML through an `array.join()` and inserting via `innerHTML` is actually the fastest method.

Comment: The 1000x1000 of 16x16 was an example.  More realistic is a 600x400 grid.  However, there could be thousands of divs in the background at any given time that "turn on".  Thank you for the post, it gives me a general idea on the performance.  :)

Comment: There no need to use `createElement` zillions of times, far more efficient to create one div and clone it. And you can also create a div, then "inject" markup of 1,000,000 divs as the innerHTML (which is effectively what the jQuery example does).

Comment: Add a plain js clone method to the [jsperf script](http://jsperf.com/render-in-memory-vs-direct-dom-insertion/2), it's hugely faster than jQuery.

Comment: @RobG It's definitely faster, but part of the reason your benchmark ran thousands of times faster is because the DIV text node was left out. I ran an [updated jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/render-in-memory-vs-direct-dom-insertion/7) and found more modest gains. Using native browser methods on my Intel Q8200 quad core with Chrome, I find that it's about twice as fast. On some browsers (FireFox, IE, maybe others), the fastest method is actually build a long string of HTML and inject it all via innerHTML.

Comment: The OP wants to emulate a canvas, so there is no need for any content in the div, all it needs is a 1px padding on one side and a background colour, which can be applied using a class. Better to remove the text node from the alternatives. innerHTML is fast, but not particularly elegant. :) There are likely faster ways of generating the HTML than one at a time, I'll add to the test case.

Comment: I agree, the OP does want DIVs without content, but for the purposes of benchmarking we ought to compare apples to apples. Yeah, I'm not a fan of the `innerHTML` method either--if you want to bind event handlers to elements during render, it's impossible to do that with the `innerHTML` method. Injecting HTML via `innerHTML` forces you to bind event handlers after DOM insertion.

Comment: But I'm also not a huge fan of directly using the native browser methods for DOM insertion. I often have to inject large highly nested chunks of HTML; building it out block by block with `createDocumentFragment`, `cloneNode`, `createElement`, etc would give me an aneurysm ;). jQuery is really handy because you can pass in a large string of HTML, it'll break it out and use the proper native methods to add it to memory. There's some overhead to that process, but in practice I think it's necessary because of how much programmer time it saves and how much less complicated your code will be.

Answer (score 0):

General answer: it depends mainly on your application, and we know very few about this. in general the more complex your HTML gets, the longer will it take to render in your browser, it will take more memory, DOM changes will be more expensive etc. The same goes for your matching CSS rules and Javascript manipulations.

I would suggest the following approach: try either approach. Start of small and raise the number of elements in HTML to what you want to have in the end. Try in different browsers, perhaps on mobile machines etc. Try to measure CPU and Memory usage and work from this.